# Parsing Options using Apache Commons Library

Tags: java, java-stream, apache-commons-cli

This might be sort of a noob question, but I am using the `import org.apache.commons.cli.*;` to set up my command line parser application.

This is how I am setting up my option.

`Option n = Option.builder().hasArg(true).option("n").build();`

`options.addOption(n);`

In one of our scenarios, we have a particular case where the input looks something like this `"-n", "2", "3"`. Now this is not a valid scenario, because n should fail if you provide more than one value, without the "-n" flag.

Invalid: "-n", "2", "3"

Valid: "-n", "2", "-n", "3"

I was able to get the valid scenario working, but I am unable to get the invalid scenario working. because when I use getOptionValues(), I only get back 2 and not 3. Does anyone know how I can grab 3 too, and fail the invalid scenario.

Thanks.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CommandLine.getArgList()` to check for such "trailing" arguments,

```
    CommandLine cmd = parser.parse(options, new String[] {"-n", "2", "3"});
    assertTrue(cmd.hasOption(n));

    assertEquals("[3]", cmd.getArgList().toString());
```

So you can fail parsing if `cmd.getArgList()` is not empty to catch such cases.